# Trigger defined kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes

I have a simple job that is defined in a YAML file similar to the one below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: check_deps
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: production-container
        image: registry.company.com/app:master
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: production
        args:
        - python
        - check_dependencies
      restartPolicy: Never
```

I want to trigger this job from the CI, and receive an information if it failed or succeeded.
Just a simple command like:

```
kubectl run job --name=check_deps --watch
```

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) says, that I need to create job from yaml, read its output and then delete it in 3 separate steps. I can create a script to do that, but maybe there is a built in solution that would allow me to achieve my goal?

I'm running kubernetes on bare metal CentOs, vesion 1.11 of client and server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such build-in functionality in Kubernetes. You can use `kubectl create` command but you still have to write your own script for running it and checking statuses.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/check_deps`. You still need to create and remove you job before and after, but with that command you should end up with a rather clean and simple approach after all.